# How do I display the selected value differently from the value on the dropdown menu?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am learning materialUI and trying to make it so that the the dropdown displays the full region name but when the option is selected it will display as the value (e.g. 'NA1'). Is there any way to do this?

[image]

My current code:

```
        <FormControl
          sx={{position: 'absolute', right: '2%', top: '50%', transform: 
            'translateY(-50%)'}}
        >
          <Select
            size='small'
            value={region}
            onChange={updateRegion}
          >
            <MenuItem value='NA1'>North America</MenuItem> 
            <MenuItem value='JP1'>Japan</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='KR'>Korea</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='EUW1'>Europe West</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='EUN1'>Europe North</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='BR1'>Brazil</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

save the value selected and put key and value property equal value property :

```
const [region, setRegion] = useState({key:'',value:''});
const updateRegion=(e)=>{
    setRegion(state=>({key:e.target.value,value:e.target.value}));
}
<FormControl
sx={{position: 'absolute', right: '2%', top: '50%', transform:
    'translateY(-50%)'}}
>
<Select
size='small'
value={region}
onChange={updateRegion}
    >
    <MenuItem value='NA1'>North America</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value='JP1'>Japan</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value='KR'>Korea</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value='EUW1'>Europe West</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value='EUN1'>Europe North</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value='BR1'>Brazil</MenuItem>
</Select>
</FormControl>
```